# Simple Flask app to insert data to database works locally but wouldn't work when deployed

Tags: python-3.x, api, flask, psycopg2, pythonanywhere

I have built a simple app that grabs the data from POST request and puts it into a database (Postgesql) using Flask. I have tested it locally and everything works as it should. But when I deploy it to pythonAnywhere it gives me the 500 error back when I POST the data to my app. It works though when I don't use psycopg2 and just return the fetched result back. 
Please see my code below.
Also, I am relatively new to web development

```
import psycopg2
from flask import Flask, request


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def hello_world():

    req_data = request.get_json()
    info = req_data['info']

    conn1 = psycopg2.connect(
        user = "some_user",
        password = "some_password",
        host = "some_host",
        port = "5432",
        database = "some_db"
    )
    conn1.autocommit = True
    cursor1 = conn1.cursor()

    sql = "INSERT INTO amber_list (user_id, description) VALUES ('{}', '{}')".format(str(info), str(info))
    cursor1.execute(sql)
    conn1.close()

    return '''
           Database was successfully updated with "{}"
           '''.format(info)
```

Also this is the sample string I am fetching

```
{
    "info" : "Seems to be working :)"
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that the database connection you're using in code locally is the same as the one in your production environment?

Comment: Have you checked the error logs for your site?  They're linked from the "Web" page inside PythonAnywhere, and the most recent error will be at the end of the file.

Comment: Thanks. Since it was my first attempt deploying something I was not familiar with logs on the server. Just found the mistake in there and its due to my subscription. Thanks